# Having Trouble outputting to a file

Tags: python

I have this simple code here

```
import os

path = (raw_input("Enter dir: "))   
f = open('script_list.log', 'w')
for dirpath, dirname, filenames in os.walk(path):
  for filename in [f for f in filenames]:
    f.write(str(filename) + "\n")
    print os.path.join(dirpath, filename)
```

When I run it I am getting the following

```
Enter dir: scripts
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\CRichards\My Documents\My Dropbox\this_code.py", line 8, in <module>
    f.write(str(filename) + "\n")
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'write'
```

I know it must be something simple, I just can't see it.

Comment: Yes I changed the f =open and f.write to log=open and log.write that solved it.  Fresh set of eyes and all that. Thanks very much

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're rebinding `f` in the loop when you do `[f for f in filenames]`. When you get to the point where `f.write` is called, `f` is the last member of `filenames`, so it's a string. Rename the outer `f` to something like `log` or `output`, or better, get rid of the useless list comprehension:

```
for file name in filenames:
```

suffices.

(List comprehensions don't introduce a new scope.)

Comment: That solved it as soon as I saw your reply, I totally over looked the f for f as soon as I changed the f = open and f.write to log it worked first time.  Thanks to everyone that helped

Answer (score 3):

```
for filename in [f for f in filenames]:
```

should instead be

`for filename in filenames:`

Comment: Solved now my code is import os

path = (raw_input("Enter dir: "))
log = open('script_list.log', 'w')
for dirpath, dirname, filenames in os.walk(path):
  for filename in [f for f in filenames]:
    log.write(str(filename) + "\n")
    print os.path.join(dirpath, filename)